# Stop & Replace running threads with new threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
for (APCounter = start; APCounter < Stager.InstructionsMemory.Length; APCounter++)
{
    PipelineInitializor();
    int i1 = APCounter;
    int i = APCounter;
    tasks[i] = new BlockingCollection<Func<object>>();
    tasks[i].Add(() => Fetch(i1));
    tasks[i].Add(() => Decode(i1));
    tasks[i].Add(() => ALURes(i1));
    tasks[i].Add(() => Memory(i1));
    tasks[i].Add(() => WriteB(i1));
    InstructionThread[i] = new Thread(() => Worker(i1, tasks[i1]));
    InstructionThread[i1].Start();
}
```

Those are couple of threads that needs to be replaced by new threads that carry same kind of data object, but with new tasks data.

I've tried using the [`Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) method (which is not recommended), and it caused everything to halt execution, and no matter what function I call, nothing starts execution again.

Comment: Why `i` and `i1`?  Why not just `i` for both?

Comment: Okay, I'll use it for both. Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the Task Parallel Library and the Task class, it has the capability of 
cancellation.

"Replacing" a thread doesn't make any sense.  You can start a new thread to process the same data; but, if you have no way for the other thread to stop itself you can't reliably stop it.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the method abort () is not recommended. If it's an infinite loop, a boolean used to stop the thread without the abortion.

```
bool run = true;
Thread thread = new Thread(method);
thread.start();

private void method()
{
  while(run)
  {

  }
}
```

To stop the thread, just set the boolean to false and normally, you can restart it later (or a other)